# Removing a child element in a container using removeChild() does not work

Tags: javascript, onclick, removechild

I've created a sample file that has adding and removing children elements in a mother element. The adding was successful, but I'm having a problem in removing children elements. The goal is every single click of remove button removes a child element.

```js
 var adds = document.querySelector('#add');
    var remove = document.querySelector('#remove');
    var section = document.querySelector('section');
    var div;
    
    adds.onclick = function() {
     div = document.createElement('div');
     section.appendChild(div);
     div.classList.add('style');
    };
    
    // THE PROBLEM
    remove.onclick = function() {
     while(section.children.length !== 0) {
      for(var c in section.children) {
       section.removeChild(div[c]);
      }
     }
    };
```

```css
  section {
        display: flex;
     background: #0ff;
     height: 100px;
     padding: 8px;
    }
    section > div {margin: 0 1px;}
    .style {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>
    
    <section class="container"></section>
<br>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Comment: div is not an array, so div[c] is undefined

Comment: Why do you check children of section element if you want to delete childs from div?

Comment: @Del What should I change it to?

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with my code?

This line

```
section.removeChild(div[c]);
```

`div` could be undefined here and anyways, sections's children are not necessarily div's children

so change it to

```
section.removeChild(section.children [c]);
```

Also, `while` is not necessary

```
remove.onclick = function() {
        for(var c in section.children) {
            section.removeChild(section.children[c]);
        }
};
```

**EDIT**

> The goal is every single click of remove button removes a child
>   element.

```
remove.onclick = function() {
        if(section.children length ) {
            section.removeChild(section.children[0]);
        }
};
```

changed `for` with `if`

Comment: You can also replace the `for` loop with : `while (section.hasChildNodes()) section.removeChild(section.childNodes[0]);`

Comment: @Patrick2607 `hasChildNodes` also deletes the text nodes. I am not sure if OP intends to do that.

Comment: I believe OP wants to remove one element per click: 
> The goal is every single click of remove button removes *a* child element.

Comment: I changed the `div[c]` to `section[c]` but it's still not working

Comment: @jtrixx16 made the changes, please check

Comment: I edited it. It worked but it removes more than 1 children. And when I changed the `for` to `if`, both the add and remove had errors

Comment: Error says "Unexpected token var" in `if(var c in section.children)`